# Finding a characteristic function of a product of two normal random variables

Tags: random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let us define two, independent random variables $X, Y$. We know that:
$$X - N(0, 1) \wedge Y-N(0,1).$$
Our task is to find characteristic function of a product of $X, Y$.
I know that:

1. $\varphi_X(t) = e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$,
2. $\varphi_{X+Y}(t) = \varphi_X(t) \varphi_Y(t)$.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to find $\varphi_{XY}$. I would appreciate any tips or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: as a consequence of Fubini's theorem and the independence of $X$ and $Y$, 
$$
\mathbb E\left[f(X,Y)\right]=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y)\mathrm dP_X(x)\mathrm dP_Y(y)=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y) \mathrm dP_Y(y)\mathrm dP_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb E\left[f(x,Y)\right] \mathrm dP_X(x).
$$
for all measurable function $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$. Apply this to $f\colon (x,y)\mapsto e^{itxy}$ and use the expression for the characteristic function of a standard normal random variable.